# Modal window with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've made a Modal window with React and Redux. I wanted to avoid local state so I used Redux to keep info is the modal is open or not.

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Modal.css';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import { isModalOpen } from '../actions/index';

const Modal = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const modalOpen = useSelector(state => state.isModalOpen);

    const closeModal = () => {
        dispatch(isModalOpen(false));
    }
    if(!modalOpen) return null;
    
    return(
        <div id="modal-container" onClick={closeModal}>
            <div id="modal">
                <span onClick={closeModal}>Close</span>
                <h2>Modal</h2>
                <p>description</p>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import Modal from './Modals/Modal';
import Contents1 from './Modals/Contents1';
import Contents2 from './Modals/Contents2';
import { isModalOpen } from './actions/index';

import './App.css';

const App =  () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const openModal1 = () => {
    dispatch(isModalOpen(true)); 
  };

  const openModal2 = () => {
    dispatch(isModalOpen(true));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openModal1}>Open Modal 1</button>     
      <Modal>
        <Contents1 />
      </Modal>

      <button onClick={openModal2}>Open Modal 2</button>
      <Modal>
        <Contents2 />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I have one button opening one Modal everything is okay. However if I want to have another button opening the Modal window with other Contents2, it doesn't work.

How to change the code so the first button opens the Modal with Contents1, and the second button opens the Modal with Contents2?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if you click the `Open Modal 2` and then `Open Modal 1`? does it open the 2nd one and dosent open the 1st one? If so it could simply be a state thing. You dont reset the redux state from `true` ti `false` when modal closes. Hence dispatching the same value does not trigger a re-render. If so, you need to trigger a dispatch to set the state to `false` on modal close. A simple test: `console.log(isModalOpen )` inside the `openModal1` and `openModal2` before `dispatch` to check if the initial state is `false` or some other value

Comment: Both Modals are open when you click any of the buttons. The Modals overlap each other and the one with Contents2 is on top.

Answer (score 1):

Why were you avoiding the usage of local state?? Since both modals are being used inside that component it makes much more sense to use local state than to store it in a global state. It also makes the code shorter and cleaner IMO.

```
const App =  () => {
  const [currentModal, setCurrentModal] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentModal('modal1')}>Open Modal 1</button>     

      <button onClick={() => setCurrentModal('modal2')}>Open Modal 2</button>
      {currentModal ? (
        <Modal handleModalClose={() => setCurrentModal(null)}>
           {currentModal === "modal1" ? <Contents1 /> : <Contents2 />}
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And then the `modal.js` file would also be simplified

```
    const Modal = props => (
        <div id="modal-container" onClick={props.handleModalClose}>
            <div id="modal">
                <span onClick={props.handleModalClose}>Close</span>
                <h2>Modal</h2>
                <p>description</p>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
     );

     export default Modal;
```

If you still want to use redux you should store the modal name instead of just the open flag and have a mapping between modals names and components

```
import modals from '../utils/modals'
const Modal = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const currentModal = useSelector(state => state.currentModal);

    if(!currentModal) return null;
    
    return(
        <div id="modal-container" onClick={closeModal}>
            <div id="modal">
                <span onClick={closeModal}>Close</span>
                <h2>Modal</h2>
                <p>description</p>
                {modals[currentModal}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

And `modals.js` would export an object like this

```
export default modals = {
    modal1: <ModalContent1 />,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Redux state you'll need to handle multiple modals by some unique identifier, otherwise you are telling any modal to be open. Then pass the "id" along in your dispatch function.

Comment: Thank tou very much for your help guys. I just wanted to have a modal frame 'Modal' and to include different contents in it. And I wanted to know at every moment if that Modal is open by having a flag in the Redux store. It seems it works only with one Modal per component.